# Searching of elements within a list in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following list

```
b = [[1,2], [1,3], [2,4], [2,5], [3,4], [3,5], [4,6], [5,6]]
```

I want to check the condition when second element of list b is equal to its first element.

```
len_b = len(b);
for i in range(0, len_b):
    if b[i][1] == b[0][i]:
        print 'anything'
```

but, whenever I execute this I have the `IndexError: list index out of range.`

Comment: `b[0][i]` should be `b[i][0]`

Comment: b[1][0] == b[1][1]. If you only want to compare second element of list you don't need to iterate it.

Comment: The error has gone; but without the print statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code , it should be:

```
b = [[1,2], [1,3], [2,4], [2,5], [3,4], [3,5], [4,6], [5,6]]
len_b = len(b)          # not need of semi-colon here
for i in range(0, len_b):      # range(len_b) is enough
    if b[i][1] == b[i][0]:     # see here
        print 'anything'
```

Let me introduce you with `filter` and `lambda`:

```
filter(lambda x:x[0]==x[1], b)
```

Answer (score 4):

Hackaholic's solutions fixes the issue but the Pythonic way to do this is to use tuple unpacking not indexing:-

```
>>> b = [[1,2], [1,3], [2,4], [2,5], [3,4], [3,5], [4,6], [5,6]]
>>> for x, y in b:                                              
        if x == y:
            print 'anything'
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the provided answers, there is a simple comprehension you can use to get a list of all items satisfying the criteria:

```
b = [[1,2], [1,3], [2,4], [2,5], [3,4], [3,5], [4,6], [5,6]]
c = [[x,y] for x, y in b if x == y]
```

This can be handy if you want to filter a list.

Answer (score 1):

Fix as:

```
len_b = len(b);
for i in range(0, len_b):
    if b[i][0] == b[i][1]:
        print 'anything'
```

Sensory, you could have more pythonic way to write code, like:

```
for x, y in b:
    if x == y:
        print 'xxx'
```